# Referencing packages/projects outside of solution during development phase

Tags: c#, .net-core, reference, nuget

My team has recently migrated from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1, our products used to reference our class libraries via DLL references and we didn't use NuGet.
In this recent change, we have decided to start using NuGet and PackageReferences.

So we have multiple solutions, for simplicity, let's say we have ***ProjectA*** in ***SolutionA*** and ***ProjectB*** in ***SolutionB***.
***ProjectB*** needs to reference ***ProjectA***, so we packed ***ProjectB*** and pushed it to our private NuGet repository. Now ***ProjectB*** has a PackageReference to ***ProjectA***. However, when we want to develop new features in ***ProjectA*** and test them in ***ProjectB*** , we must pack and push those changes.

We would like to avoid using DLL references or any other solution that would require our developers to remember to do before pushing their changes to the Source Control.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this? I don't know about that, but we basically follow the steps in [this post by Jay Barden](https://capgemini.github.io/development/debugging-into-a-nuget-package/). Perhaps a similar approach will work for you?

Basically, each developer needs to set up a folder on their machine that will serve as a local package feed. `%USERPROFILE%\Feeds`, for example. Then have everyone add that folder as a feed in the usual manner (Package Sources under the Options menu).

Then, in **ProjectA** you can add a Post Build event that will automatically create a nuget package and copy it to the local feeds folder. You can use `dotnet pack` to create the package, or make sure everyone has `nuget.exe` on their path and use that instead. You can include symbols when you package **ProjectA** so that it can easily be debugged from **ProjectB**. Once you've created the package, use `XCOPY` to move `*.nupkg` files to the local feeds folder.

Then when testing in **ProjectB** you update the dependency on **PackageA** to the newly created version in the local feed and do your testing.

That might sound like a lot, but setting up the local feed is a one time per machine thing. And the post build event is a one time per project thing. Once you've done that, your developers never have to manually pack and push **ProjectA** before moving to **ProjectB** for testing; it happens automatically when they build **ProjectA**. Furthermore, **ProjectA** doesn't get pushed to your private repository until it's checked in to source control and goes through your release process. This way, your private repository doesn't get filled with pre-release or broken versions of **ProjectA** while the developers smooth out any bugs in their changes.